# Place divs with "for" loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to make multiple `divs`, all of the same `size` and same `top` position. Each new `div` must be offset by the `width` and `position` of the last. Please be aware: I'm very new to this!

Here's what an idea of what I want to do:

```
<style>

div {
    height:98%;
    width:1.4%;
    background: red;
}

</style>

<script> 
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
        var x = 0.6%;
        var y = x + 1.4%;
        $("div").position({
            left: y;
        });
    }
};
</script> 

<div></div>
```

So let's say the first rectangle's position was 2%, the next would be 3.4% then 4.8%...

Comment: Normally I'd assume you have a very good reason for doing this. But since you say you are very new to this, I'd like to ask if you are aware that you are doing something that can easily be solved with CSS alone?

Comment: It's my second day of JQuery, HTML, and CSS! I've never used them before in my life... But please do tell!

Oh I forgot to mention that I want these rectangles to animate afterwards, but not all at the same time. If you're talk about using relative position I tried but couldn't get the effect I wanted.

Comment: Is this a "Find the 10 errors" game? 1. No recursion (the question promised recursion). 2. `for` statement never ends ( i = 60) 3.  }); }); }); 4. `x` = is a constant and so is `y` 5. there is no 'placing' of divs as the question promised 6. $("div") affects all divs. Which is only one. 7. Missing `<body>` and what not.

Comment: It was only a section of the code which I know is wrong. If it wasn't I wouldn't be asking... I just wanted to give an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish to the answerers. Please read the question before answering next time. It'll save everyone time.

Comment: @ılǝ 2. Code inside block gets ignored: `i = 60` is the condition, but `i` is initialized as `0`. That's not a infinite loop.

Comment: @GuiImamura the question was edited - originally it had `for (var i=0; i=60; i++)` . @user3476972 I did read it carefully as you can see from my comment. If you really want to save everyone some time - use a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) .

Comment: @ılǝ My bad. I forgot that `i=60` doesn't return `false`. For some reason, I thought it would check `i==60`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll just assume that your question was "why doesn't it run?":

1. The syntax is wrong at the `for (var i=0; i=60; i++)`. I believe
   that you meant to write `i < 60` as the loop condition.
2. There is too many closing parenthesis: `)`, after the `for` statement.
3. You're not creating many `divs`, you're just moving the only one that exists in your code.
4. Your `x` isn't increasing. So `y` will contain `2.0%` for ever.
5. You do realise that when it finally works, you'll just have a screen filled by red `divs` side by side, and it'll look like one giant red `div`, right?
6. Please tell me you're including jQuery somehow (e.g. by running it on JSFiddle).

I recommend you spend more time learning the proper syntax of JavaScript in first place. Challenge yourself with `arrays` first, maybe? Creating new `Objects` is lots of fun! Then, learn how to manipulate DOM.

Comment: No my question was more, "how can I do this." Sorry, I should've made that clearer. The code was more to give an idea. After writing it, it did occur to me that it was only changing the position, not creating others. The rectangles are also supposed to be side by side only.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I'll change my answer soon... Let me spend a little more time on jQuery first, hahah.